# run python script from flask

Tags: python, flask, web

I have a python script (script.py) that when I run it in the console it keeps receiving data in JSON format, now I want to visualize the output of the console on a web page or to be able to execute the script.py and capture the output to view in the browser, from what I have read I understand that with FLASK I could do it, an example or guide to achieve it.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def code():
    out = open(r'output.py', 'r').read()
    return exec(out)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////

builtins.RuntimeError

RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-9'.
Traceback (most recent call last)

```
File "..//python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2301, in __call__

return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

File "..//python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2287, in wsgi_app

response = self.handle_exception(e)

File "..//python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1733, in handle_exception

reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "..//python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise

raise value

File "..//python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2284, in wsgi_app

response = self.full_dispatch_request()

File "..//python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1807, in full_dispatch_request

rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

File "..//python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1710, in handle_user_exception

reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "..//python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise

raise value

File "..//python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1805, in full_dispatch_request

rv = self.dispatch_request()

File "..//python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1791, in dispatch_request

return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

File "/usr/share/server/www/test/index1.py", line 9, in dynamic_page

return exec(file)

File "<string>", line 60, in <module>
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
output.py

#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json
import sys

from phone import Runn, BReporter, EventHandler

class NoOpEventHandler(EventHandler):

```
def on_event(self, event):
    self._reporter.on_event(event)
```

class VerboseNoOpEventHandler(NoOpEventHandler):

```
FILTER_EVENTS = False
```

class JsonReporter(BReporter):

```
def __init__(self):
    self._has_first_line = False

def on_event(self, event):

    json_data = json.dumps(dict(event), sort_keys=True)

    if self._has_first_line:
        sys.stdout.write(',')
    else:
        sys.stdout.write('[')
        self._has_first_line = True

    sys.stdout.write('\n  {}'.format(json_data))

def close(self):
    sys.stdout.write('\n]')
```

reporter = JsonReporter()

runner = Runn([
'tcp://test123:test123@127.0.0.1:5038',
], reporter, handler=NoOpEventHandler)
runner.run()

Comment: `open().read()` leaks a resource handle. Always `with` or `.close()`

Answer (score 0):

just use this; you must set `debug = True`. You do not have to provide host for testing.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

you should see an output like that on terminal;

```
* Serving Flask app "my_flask_app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: xxx-xxx-xxx
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

open a web browser and copy paste: http://127.0.0.1:5000/

Comment: He does need to provide `host` if he is testing on another machine.

Answer (score 0):

I saved your code in `tmp.py` and just ran it as `python tmp.py`.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def code():
    out = open(r'output.py', 'r').read()
    return exec(out)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

run it as below:

```
   (flaskvenv) C:...>python tmp.py
```

Here is the output:

```
* Serving Flask app "tmp" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: XXX-XXX-XXX
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

That means the code runs. You might have another problem!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the exec(out) . Actually , exec is a dynamic execution of a program which can either be a string or object code, and it does not return anything , it just executes a program and returns None.

If you run your code without trying to return the exec(out) you won't get error.